# android html5 canvas why not capture draw line?

Tags: android, html, canvas

this is html5 painting test app

1. run app
2. draw line
3. press "capture"
4. not capture line
5. tab is not capTure
   [click screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahQeE.png)
6. Galaly 4 is capTure
   [click screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1BiU.png)

Comment: Hi SundayPark, you should ask this question on GitHub in the issues section of the library you are trying to use: https://github.com/JooilPark/testScreenShot/issues

Comment: ok, open My issues .

Answer (score 0):

add webView option

mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

is option use.

capture OK.